# Jquery Contains Selector for A TR with a specific Name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to search an expense type from a table. The table row has a class called `expense_type` and a name is the name of the expense type.

```
$('.search_expense').keyup(function() 
{
    if($(this).val() != '') 
    { 
        $('.expense_type').hide();
        $( 'tr[name*=$(this).val()]' ).show();
    }
    else
    { 
        $('.expense_type').show(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Does the row exist in DOM at page load?

Comment: yes, it load the whole table, then you can search

Comment: Ok, maybe it's just that when you bind the event, the rows aren't loaded. Bind the keyup event after the load. If you can't figure it out, post all relevant javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `concatenation` properly,

```
$('tr[name*=' + $(this).val()+ ']').show();
```

Full code,

```
$('.search_expense').keyup(function() {
  var condition = ($(this).val() != '');
  $('.expense_type').toggle(!condition);
  $('tr[name*=' + $(this).val() + ']').toggle(condition);
});
```

Comment: follow up though, what if i want to disregard capitalization? for example, "Rent" can be search as just "rent"

Comment: @user2530985 Nope, by default jquery searches by considering the cases.

Answer (score 0):

you placed `$(this).val()` in `double quotes i.e ""`. Jquery not evaluate the value of input. so try like this

```
$('.search_expense').keyup(function() {
            if($(this).val() != '') { $('.expense_type').hide();
            $( 'tr[name*='+$(this).val()+']' ).show(); //change this line
            }
            else{ $('.expense_type').show(); }
          });
```